# In Eldritch Horror, how do you deal with cases when an event forces you to draw a condition card that you already have?

Tags: eldritch-horror

The rules state that a player cannot choose to take a condition when he already has one of that type.

How do you deal with cases when an event **forces** you to draw a condition card?

As an example, let's say my character has a debt card and he is asked by an event in the game to draw one. Do you

- simply ignore this step in the event resolution
- flip the card you previously owned and that's it
- flip the card you previously owned and draw another one (ouch)
- other?

Comment: @tsuma534 I agree that the answer is the same but not the question. If anything, that other question should marked as a duplicate of this newer, more general question.

Comment: @Samthere Actually neither of the questions is more general. This one asks only about a forced gain, and the other one only about a willing gain.
The problem is, the question here is better, but answers are better there. And a guideline for duplicates tells to chose the question with better answers.

Comment: @tsuma534 Having looked at them a bit more, you're right about neither being more general. In fact, each one mentions the answer to the other before asking its own question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very detailed [reference guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf) covers this case. From p.4, *"Conditions"*:

> An investigator cannot have multiple copies of the same  Condition. If
>   he would gain a Condition that he already has a  copy of, he does not
>   gain another copy of that Condition.

Comment: Thanks @ire_and_curses for the answer and the link. I didn't played the game on my copy so I didn't have access to the reference book... By reading the reference guide I also found this sentence in the "Golden Rule Paragraph on the first page: "If an effect uses the word “cannot,” that effect is absolute." In this precise case having a debt before drawing the event is more a benefit than a drawback then ;-).

Comment: Glad to help. :) Yes, the reference guide is very useful. It's amazingly complete. I suppose you could see it as a benefit in the sense that you got something for nothing this time round. But you still have the original debt to worry about!  I just noticed you also mentioned card flipping. It's helpful to know that in general the only thing that flips the card is the condition described on the card itself.

Answer (score 3):

**ire_and_curses's** answer is correct, you can not gain multiple copies of the same condition. There are, however, two caveats to this that are important to note.

1. Curses and Blessings have their own rules for handling multiple copies. If you were to gain a second one of either, you flip them instead. This is printed on those cards and, as always, text on cards overrules general rules.

   In the future more conditions with special handling for these cases may be added.
2. This rule means that you can not "pay" for an effect if you already have the condition required. This means that when you are instructed to "gain a specific condition" or something else (worse) happens, you have to resolve the "something else" if you already have that condition.

   Same goes for text like "you may gain a specific condition to gain something 'good'", you can't pay for the good stuff if you already have the condition.